# Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, prove that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

If $  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x \gt 0 $} \\
0, & \text{if $x \le 0$}
\end{cases}$

In this case, $|x| \le \delta$. How should I approach $|f(x)|$? Should I treat the right hand and left hand limit differently or is there another way?

Comment: It would only be $|f(x)|$ to make small if you were trying to show the limit at zero is $0.$ But it isn't, so that's not what you need to do. Try taking $\epsilon = 1/2$ and showing there is no $\delta$ which can work.

Comment: @coffeemath If we take $\epsilon = 1/2$, then $|f(x)| \le 1/2$, how do we associate this with $\delta$?

Comment: No matter how small $\delta$ is, if we let $x=\delta/2$ we have $|x-0|<\delta$ and yet $|f(x)-f(0)|=|1-0|=1,$ which fails to be within $\varepsilon = 1/2$ of $f(0)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Take for example $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}.$

we have $f(0)=0$.

$$\implies (f(0)-\epsilon,f(0)+\epsilon)=(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$$

but

$$\forall \eta>0\;\; f((0-\eta,0+\eta))=\{0,1\}\not \subset (f(0)-\epsilon,f(0)+\epsilon)$$

qed.

Comment: Since the function is constant except at a point, I would have preferred to look at $f(\delta)$ and $f(-\delta)$, which both equal $1$ for all $\delta > 0$ and are therefore not within $\epsilon$ of $f(0)$, but using $f$ evaluated on the interval is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\delta > 0$.  Choose $x \in (0, \delta)$.  Then $|f(x) - f(0)| = |1 - 0| = 1$, hence $f \not \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: This seems a bit backwards compared to direct usage of the definition. You would usually fix $\epsilon=1/2$, and then show that no matter what $\delta>0$ you choose, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Why are you setting $\epsilon = 1/2$?  Just call it $1/2$ if you need some particular value.  But there's really no point.  You choose an arbitrary number $\delta > 0$ and show that $f(x)$ stays a fixed distance away from $f(0)$.  The $1/2$ is irrelevant to the argument.

Comment: The definition of continuity says "For any $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that..." That mean that in order to disprove continuity directly from the definition, you have to show that there exists an $\epsilon$ for which there is no $\delta$. $1/2$ is such an $\epsilon$. It is _quite_ relevant to the argument, although it is certainly not unique.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the definition of continuity.  But when you write "set \epsilon = 1/2" it makes it sound like you have an at most tenuous grasp on what's going on in the definition in the first place.  Just because we're talking about continuity doesn't mean you need to write "epsilon" somewhere on the page.

There's no point in singling out 1/2 here.  The meat of the argument is the fact that f(x) is a fixed distance from f(0) for all x > 0.  The choice of 1/2 is irrelevant to what's actually going on.